# An error will be output when migrating data to Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

Below is the error contents outputted when migrating data from magento 1.9.3.1 to magento 2.2.6.

Please tell me how to fix the error.

```
[root@windows magento]# php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.1/config.xml

[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2018-11-30 11:53:01][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
58% [================>-----------] Remaining Time: 1 sec

  [PDOException]                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4175' for key 'WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID'
```

Comment: from my side best way to migration first repair your  database using any tool than after try migration process

Comment: Did you try with the -a and -r switch?